Git changes shows out of scope changes
We recently switched to Azure DevOps and we have a small usability issue. We have currently 482 applications. We split them into groups that works somewhat together. So i have for example a repos with 5 applications in it.
When i open 1 of the 5 solutions that include about 20+ projects and only 1 is shared trough the 5 other applications and the other 5 each have 10 to 15 projects of their own.
The problem is that we often need to work on 2-3 applications at the same time and when that happen on the same repos all changes in the repo shows in the Git Changes of any solution in the same repo. Unlike SVN that was filtering to only show the changes of the project in the solution.
I cannot find if there is an option to deal with this issue. I see a filter box but i don't find anyway other than having both Git changes and solution explorer side by side.

Not sure if I understand your issue, maybe try adding a few screenshots to your question?

I can't share a picture of project due to internal policies where i work. Take a simple example, 1 repo in c:\repo, that has 2 solution project in 2 sub folder, c:\repo\ProjectA\a.sln and c:\repo\ProjectB\b.sln, if you change something in ProjectA and then open ProjectB in the git change window of ProjectB you see changes of ProjectA when it's not event a project in that solution.

Are both projects in the same repo? if yes I think this is the expected behavior of git

This behavior is by-design to use Git for repositories version control .
The core part of any Git workflow is modifying files and committing the changes in those files. This is the expected behavior when we work remotely with the Git provider of GitHub or Azure DevOps, or with no provider at all.
In your scenario, Git will compare all the files in your single repo local path c:\repo with those in your remote repo from Azure DevOps, and then display the files that have been changed. These changes are equivalent to what you would see when you run the git status command.

Therefore, the items in the Git Changes window are the modified files from our local repo compared to the remote repo, rather than within a solution, project or any sub folder.
Since it shows all the changes between the local and remote Git repos, we can decide to make a git commit, pull or push.
